# Trying to get a list of a single field from all the documents in my Mongo database

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the last driver.  My documents are of the form

```
{
    "ItemID": 292823,
    ....
}
```

First problem: I'm attempting to get a list of all the ItemIDs, and then sort them.  However, my search is just pulling back all the _id, and none of the ItemIDs.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  var f = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
  var p = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include(x => x["ItemID"]);
  var found= collection.Find(f).Project<BsonDocument>(p).ToList().ToArray();
```

When I attempt to query the output, I get the following.

```
found[0].ToJson()
"{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"56fc4bd9ea834d0e2c23a4f7\") }"
```

It's missing ItemID, and just has the mongo id.

Solution: I messed up the case.  It's itemID, not ItemID.  I'm still having trouble with the sorting.

Second problem: I tried changing the second line to have x["ItemID"].AsInt32, but then I got an InvalidOperationException with the error

> Rewriting child expression from type 'System.Int32' to type
>   'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue' is not allowed, because it would change the
>   meaning of the operation. If this is intentional, override
>   'VisitUnary' and change it to allow this rewrite.

I want them as ints so that I can add a sort to the query.  My sort was the following:

```
    var s = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending(x => x);
    var found= collection.Find(f).Project<BsonDocument>(p).Sort(s).ToList().ToArray();
```

Would this be the correct way to sort it?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

```
//Get all documents
var f = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;

//Just pull itemID
var p = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include(x => x["itemID"]);

//Sort ascending by itemID
var s = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("itemID");

//Apply the builders, and then use the Select method to pull up the itemID's as ints
var found = collection.Find(f)
        .Project<BsonDocument>(p)
        .Sort(s)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x=>x["itemID"].AsInt32)
        .ToArray();
```